# How to remove index.php from CodeIgniter URL?

Tags: codeigniter

[image]

`.htaccess` code it's working fine on local host but it's not working fine on godaddy server. I tried so many .htaccess codes but I am unable to solve the problem.

RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /CI/

```
        #Removes access to the system folder by users.
        #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
        #previously this would not have been possible.
        #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
        #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
        #Submitted by: Fabdrol
        #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


        </IfModule>

        <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
        </IfModule>
```

Comment: remove index.php from your config file.

Comment: You have two slashes in URL. It's because `RewriteBase` is ending with slash and later continuing with slash. Remove slashes in front of `/index.php` in two lines where `RewriteRule` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**None of .htaccess file worked for me then i made a web.config file and pasted below code there and then i uploaded that file inside of CI root folder then it worked for me.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your .htaccess path firt
it should be in root directory of your project 
and try this below htaccess code , its works for my on godaddy.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now open  /application/config/config.php and do the following changes :

```
$config['base_url']  = 'http://www.rcshoper.com/CI/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```